# 2nd xslt transformation (xhtml to xsl:fo) on client side

Tags: javascript, xhtml, xslt, xsl-fo

I have an xml document which is transformed as xhtml.
Now I need to add print button which will transform output with xsl-fo (based on antennahouse xhtml2fo.xsl http://www.antennahouse.com/XSLsample/XSLsample.htm).

This is what I came up with, but it doesn't seem to work as expected

```
              <script language="JavaScript">
            function convert()
            {
                // Load XSL
                var xsl = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
                xsl.async = false

                xsl.load("xhtml2fo.xsl")

                // Load XML 
                var xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
                xml.async = false
                // This won't work
                xml.load(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML)
                // this prints out html element as expected
                //my_window.document.write(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML)

                my_window = window.open("", "mywindow1");
                my_window.document.write(xml.transformNode(xsl))
            }
            </script>
```

How can this be made on client side? How am I able to get on demand transformation working

Comment: Do you mean you want to use the XSL-FO, and have that converted to PDF with AntennaHouse FO parser? Might be easier to just provide a download link for a PDF copy of the same page. That way you can do it all server-side, and you won't depend on browser specific plugins, or even the OS on which the browser runs. ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM") will probably not work everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you need to get the XSL-FO out of the browser and into the Antenna house XSL-FO processor executable. This violates JavaScript security principles and can not be done with JavaScript only.

You'd have to use a browser-specific solution: It could be possible with a Firefox extension, with an Active-X or Silverlight plugin in IE or with a Chrome Native Client app.

A better solution would be to do the transformation on the server side, download the transformed XSL-FO file and open it in the Antennna House executable (maybe even automatically by assigning the `.fo` extension to always open in Antenna House).

Comment: Would following solution work? <http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp>

My problem was that I couldn't do the xml load part.